# Neo4j on Graphenedb How can I improve Cypher SPEED and what does Normailzing mean on Graphenedb

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphenedb

Here is my Cypher Query

> MERGE (u:University {
>           name: $university, country: $country
>         })
>         MERGE (u)<-[:DEPARTMENT_IN]-(d:Department {
>           name: $department
>         })
>         MERGE (d)<-[:LEVEL_IN]-(l:Level {
>           name: $level
>         })
>         MERGE (l)<-[:STUDENT_OF]-(user:User {
>           firstName: $firstName,
>           lastName: $lastName,
>           password: $password,
>           email: $email,
>           username
>           dob: $dob,
>           id: $id
>         }) RETURN user, u, d, l

This works, but not very fast as what I anticipated. It takes up to 4.5 seconds to complete. Am I doing something wrong in the query, is there a faster way?

Also for the query

> MATCH (u:University {name: $university})<-[DEPARTMENT_IN]-(d:Department) RETURN d

On Graphenedb message saying "This query has been normalized"
I don't really understand.
Thanks for your answers 
[Profile of the Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD5wR.png)

Comment: Can you please share the output of PROFILE for your first query? Prefix your query with PROFILE and execute it in a neo4j browser.

Comment: There are too many MERGE clauses in the single query that degrades the performance. Try to lessen the number of MERGE in the query by creating multiple queries or use WITH to pipeline the intermediate result.

Comment: Don't forget to create Index on all the fields that you are using as a parameter in the query

Comment: Could you give an example on the pipelining with WITH

Comment: I have added an image of the profiled query